# UseState with Arrays: React + Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to add array to the useState hook but I am not able to do so. The following is my code where `response.data` is an object where as `response.data.status` is an array.

**TRYING:** `setOldBooks(response?.data?.oldBooks)`

**Error message:**

> Argument of type 'IOldBooks[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IOldBooks[] | null | undefined>'.

```
    interface IOldBooks{
        name?: string,
        count?:number
    }

    const [myBooks, setMyBooks] = useState<IBooks | null>()
    //const [oldBooks, setOldBooks] =  useState<IOldBooks[] | null>()
    const [oldBooks, setOldBooks] =  useState<IOldBooks[] | null>(null)
   

     useEffect(() => {
        const getBooks = async () => {
          try {
            const url: string = "url";
            const response = await axios.get(url);
            if(response)
                setMyBooks(response.data);
                setOldBooks(response?.data?.oldBooks)
                console.log(response?.data?.oldBooks) [{name:"a",count:1}]
                console.log("*****************", oldBooks) --> NULL
    
          } catch (err) { }}
          getBooks();
      }, []);
```

[image]

Comment: looks like you defined the interface, but useState initialization is undefined
`const [oldBooks, setOldBooks] =  useState<IOldBooks[] | null>()`. I think you should change this to `const [oldBooks, setOldBooks] =  useState<IOldBooks[] | null>(null)`

Comment: What data does return _response?.data?.oldBooks_?

Comment: I've updated my question. please kindly have a look

Comment: @Peter `const [oldBooks, setOldBooks] =  useState<Array<IOldBooks> | null>(null)`, ever tried this?

and try changing
`const response = await axios.get(url);`  to ` const response:any = await axios.get(url);`

Comment: Its still null. I tried this as well.

Comment: also, `console.log("*****************", oldBooks) --> NULL` this will shows null, because useState() is async

Comment: try consoling the `oldBooks` inside the return method, or create an useEffect to check the change like `useEffect(()=> console.log(oldBooks),[oldBooks])`

Comment: Ohh I see. Now i can see it. . It was the Async stuff. . My bad

Answer (score 1):

Using Type Assertion!

```
setOldBooks(response?.data?.oldBooks as IOldBooks[]);
```

Check out the official documentation!

[typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

Comment: It seems its not working.